# how to stack images from bottom up in Django

Tags: html, django

I'm starting with this code:

```
        {% for award in data.profile.awards %}
            <img src="media/{{ award.Medals.ribbon }}">
            {% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:3 %}
                <br />
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
```

my problem is that it goes from top down.  Meaning that it produces the first three, then a break, then another three, and repeat from there.

What I need is to go from bottom up.  in my case, If there's 4 images, I want 1 on top, and 3 on bottom.  If there's 8, then there's 2 on top, 3 in the middle, then 3 on bottom.  How do I do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could possibly try to invert your loop and count from end, like this:

```
{% if forloop.revcounter|divisibleby:3 %}
    <br>
{% endif %}
```

So, if for example you have 10 images, 1 images will be displayed, then condition will insert break, and break will be occurred after each 3 images.
Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know django template language well enough, so here it is in pure js, maybe you can translate it:

```
var total_cells = 8;
var columns = 3;
var remainder = total_cells % columns;
for(var i=1;i<=total_cells;i++){ //starting from 1 similar to django's forloop.counter
    console.log('<img>');
    if((columns - remainder + i) % columns == 0){
        console.log('<br>')
    }
}
```

The idea is to calculate the remainder from total cells divided by the number of columns, which for 8 will be 2, and then insert breaks not at every 3rd position, but at every `(3-remainder+1)` position.